# In simple C# tcp client/server program, I send 5 bytes, server sees over 400,000. What is happening?

Tags: c#, tcp, chat, tcpclient

I am trying to work out the basics of a simple tcp client/server so that I can implement a notification system that will work almost anywhere and allow "daemon" like applications to communicate.   One of the clients might be a monitor that looks at the messages and shows status of all of the reset and coordinates them, for example by pausing one or more, seeing how many files have been processed, what the status of a database is, etc.  To start, I have to have a very simple server that waits for messages from clients and broadcasts them to the other clients.  Here is my present attempt at the server(based on example in http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server.htm).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace erc.bre
{
    class NotificationServer
    {
        public static Hashtable clientsList = new Hashtable();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.IPAddress addr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(addr, 1025);
            TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
            int counter = 0;

            serverSocket.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Chat Server Started ....");
            counter = 0;
            while ((true))
            {
                counter += 1;
                clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();

                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = bytesFrom.Length; // added
                string dataFromClient = null;

                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
             //   Console.WriteLine("Bytes received: {0}", (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));

                clientsList.Add(dataFromClient, clientSocket);

                broadcast(dataFromClient + " Joined ", dataFromClient, false);

                Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient + " Joined chat room ");
                handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
                client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList);
            }

            clientSocket.Close();
            serverSocket.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string msg, string uName, bool flag)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry Item in clientsList)
            {
                TcpClient broadcastSocket;
                broadcastSocket = (TcpClient)Item.Value;
                NetworkStream broadcastStream = broadcastSocket.GetStream();
                Byte[] broadcastBytes = null;

                if (flag == true)
                {
                    broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uName + " says : " + msg);
                }
                else
                {
                    broadcastBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                }

                broadcastStream.Write(broadcastBytes, 0, broadcastBytes.Length);
                broadcastStream.Flush();
            }
        }  //end broadcast function
    }//end Main class


    public class handleClinet
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;
        string clNo;
        Hashtable clientsList;

        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo, Hashtable cList)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            this.clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 10025; // added
            this.clNo = clineNo;
            this.clientsList = cList;
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void doChat()
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;
            Byte[] sendBytes = null;
            string serverResponse = null;
            string rCount = null;
            requestCount = 0;

            while ((true))
            {
                try
                {
                    requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                    Console.WriteLine("From client - " + clNo + " : " + dataFromClient);
                    rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

                    NotificationServer.broadcast(dataFromClient, clNo, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }//end while
        }//end doChat
    } //end class handleClinet
}//end namespace
```

You will note a Console.WriteLine where I print out the number of bytes received.  I added this as I was getting an exception in the next statement that the size was out of range.  It prints out a number like 408,000 bytes.

Here is the client program, modified quite a bit because on my version of VisualStudio 2017 for Mac, I can't get anything with Windows Forms to even create a project as per the example.  Since I'm going to put the code into a web application once I get the mechanics worked out, I'm just trying to have a client enter their ID, then type a line, have the server pick it up and rebroadcast it.  Other clients would do the same from the command line ( one for each new client ).  It presently takes the userId, and sends it.  I send 'John' and it appears to send 'John$' as 5 bytes.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace erc.bre
{
    public class NotificationClient
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
        NetworkStream serverStream = default(NetworkStream);
        string readData = null;
        string display = "";
        string userName = "";
        string message = "";
        bool needsInvocation = true;
        static NotificationClient nc = new NotificationClient();

        public NotificationClient()
        {
        }

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            nc.msg();
            return 0;
        }

        private void sendUserJoined()
        {
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "$");
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }

        private void InputReceived()
        {
            readData = "Conected to Chat Server ...";
            msg();
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1025);
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + "$");
            Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} bytes as '{1}'", outStream.Length, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(outStream);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

            Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
            ctThread.Start();
        }

        private void getMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int buffSize = 0;
                byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
                string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                msg();
            }
        }

        private void msg()
        {
            if (needsInvocation)
            {
                needsInvocation = false;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Starting Client");
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Input your callerID: ");
                nc.userName = nc.ReadLine();
                nc.InputReceived();
                nc.sendUserJoined();
                nc.getMessage();
                return;
            }
            display = display + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + readData;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(display);
        }

        private string ReadLine()
        {
            string line = "";
            char ch;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter text when desired, 'enter' to end");
            do
            {
                int x = Console.Read();
                try
                {
                    ch = Convert.ToChar(x);
                    if (ch == 0x0a)
                    {
                        return line;
                    }
                }
                catch (OverflowException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Value read = {1}.", e.Message, x);
                    ch = ' ';
                }
                line += ch;
            } while (ch != 0x0a);
            return line;
        }

    }
}
```

The server console shows:

Chat Server Started ....
Bytes received: 408300

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: size
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at ConsoleApplication1.NotificationServer.Main(String[] args) in /Users/woo/Projects/erc-caml/bre/NotificationServer/NotificationServer.cs:line 33
bash: line 1: 45360 Abort trap: 6           "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet" "/Users/woo/Projects/erc-caml/bre/NotificationServer/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/NotificationServer.dll"

The client console shows:

Starting Client
Input your callerID: 
Enter text when desired, 'enter' to end
John

> > Conected to Chat Server ...
> >     Sending 5 bytes as 'John$'

Unhandled Exception:Unhandled Exception:  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: size
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at erc.bre.NotificationClient.getMessage() in /Users/woo/Projects/erc-caml/bre/NotificationMonitor/NotificationClient.cs:line 60
   at erc.bre.NotificationClient.msg() in /Users/woo/Projects/erc-caml/bre/NotificationMonitor/NotificationClient.cs:line 77

Why is the server seeing over 400,000 bytes?  Is it internally gobbling up stuff while it waits for a message?  The number appears the same no matter how long I wait, BTW.

Comment: `byte[] inStream = new byte[10025]; buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize; serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);` - the third parameter should be a max of the array size, the receive buffer size probably is 400K. There can be zero or more bytes in a buffer of 400K, the buffer size is not the size you need.

Comment: Also it would be better to check the result of `int bytesRead = serverStream.Read(...)`

Comment: Why in getMessage() method do you have a while loop?  You are using NetworkStream() which will rad entire message.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know where you got the idea that `ReceiveBufferSize` was in any way relevant to how much data has actually currently been received.

Comment: I commented out the erroneous Console.WriteLine as it was printing the wrong size as mentioned by several.  Now I receive the message and it goes into a loop.  How do I get the server to print the message, then wait on the next message?  I also limited the size of the buffer by setting it before reading to the size of the dataRead array.

Comment: As to Damien_The_Unbeliever, I got the idea from the example I referenced.  The example doesn't work.  I was trying to find out why.  I mistakenly did not look up what that argument ( number 3 ) actually meant.  It is very confusing when trying to learn and we get an example that says it works, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
```

Returns the size of the receive buffer which does not align with the amount of received bytes. Use the **Read** method of your network stream (**serverStream**) and check its result which tells you how many bytes have been read.

See [NetworkStream.Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [TcpClient.GetStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more info.